# Is it possible to copy an image from merged cells into one cell using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy/move an image from a merged cells to another sheet in one cell using Google Apps Script.

So far i've tried:
`getValue()` and `setValue()` - nothing happens
`copyTo()` - the image retains its original size
`moveTo()` - same result as copyTo()

My current code for this:

````
```
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Source');
var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Destination');

function myFunction() {
  sourceSheet.getRange('B6:B16').copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(1, 2));
}
```
````

An example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bqf08o_DtUw1lMpjA4xAeHJQWlPNVadj9E8bRs11SfU/edit

My goal is that the image in the destinationSheet is only in one cell and not multiple cells. I don't know what else I can try and I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function myFunction() {
  sourceSheet.getRange('B6:B16').copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(1, 2));
}
```

#### To:

```
function myFunction() {
  sourceSheet.getRange('B6').copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(1, 2));
}
```

or

```
function myFunction() {
  var dstRange = destinationSheet.getRange(1, 2);
  sourceSheet.getRange('B6:B16').copyTo(dstRange);
  dstRange.getMergedRanges()[0].breakApart();
}
```

- By this, an image of the merged cells of "B6:B16" is put into cell "B1" of `destinationSheet`.

Comment: I previously tried your first suggestion, and got an error "Exception: You cannot perform a copy/paste operation on an area that partially intersects a group of merged cells. Unmerge cells or select a larger area that contains the entire cell merge." I tried now again and it worked. I don't know what I did differently, but I'm glad it works now!
Your second suggestions also works. Thank you!